# How to remove ¶ (pilcrow) sign from database records

Tags: mysql

My aim is to remove ¶ (pilcrow) sign from the database records. There are thousands of records so I cannot do it manually. Is there any script available to remove ¶ (pilcrow) sign from MySQL database column?

Comment: [MySQL String functions: REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: "Replace" is perfectly okay. But how to find a pilcrow symbol before I can replace it with something?

Comment: Can you help me out with a sample script?

Comment: @jithin: Did you bother to read the manual link you were given? You tell `REPLACE` _what_ it's replacing and it finds it for you.

Comment: @ tomalak: the problem is in finding ¶ symbol. I tried REPLACE(myfield,'¶',''). But its not returning any results

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table1 SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield,'¶','') WHERE myfield LIKE '%¶%'
```

If you want to replace `¶` with an enter do:

```
UPDATE table1 SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield,'¶','\n') WHERE myfield LIKE '%¶%'
-- linefeed
or
UPDATE table1 SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield,'¶','\r\n') WHERE myfield LIKE '%¶%'
-- cariage return+linefeed.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Make sure the collation and charset of the connection and the column in question are the same:

```
DESCRIBE table1;
--  copy the column charset and collation
SET NAMES '<insert charset name>' COLLATE '<insert collation name>';
```

Now rerun the query.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: '%¶%' is not returning anything :( any thoughts?

Comment: @jithin, The collation of your DB connection is not the same as the collation of the column you are using `like` on. Make sure the collations are the same. See the updated answer.

Comment: I don't think this collation connection suggestion is valid, at least in my case.  I ran a " LIKE '%¶%' " SELECT in PhpMyAdmin and no records were found, whereas a quick review of the field in question shows that the ¶ is present in many records.  I connected directly on the server via terminal with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this (yes, major necro, but hey, I found this old thread, so someone else might also!):

I edited the column directly using phpMyAdmin, and discovered that the database was displaying a pilcrow (¶), but it was storing some other representation in the background.  No pilcrow displayed when editing the value, only a carriage return.  I selected everything after the character that immediately preceded the pilcrow (the pilcrow was the last character in the column), used that invisible string in my query, and it worked.  The working query looked like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myCol=REPLACE(myCol,'
','') WHERE myKey>'myValue'
```

Note that the query was one line of code, not two.  The invisible carriage return only makes it look like two lines.

I hope this helps someone! I investigated/tried lots of other suggestions, but none of them worked.